# Using Eclipse keystore in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I've updated an existing Eclipse app in Android Studio but can't access the keystore because Eclipse has replaced it with the .apk file. Is there any way to access the .jks file from the Eclipse .apk? 
When I build the app for release in Android Studio I choose use an existing key. the wizard looks for an existing .jks file which is not there because Eclipse has previously changed it to an .apk file when it generated a previous version. If I use eclipse to build the apk again it doesn't generate a jks file that I can use with Studio.

Comment: I can't get what you wish to say... can you add screenshot or some more description?

Comment: what is a .jks file? that doesn't sound standard at all. The keystore is a file you generate once and store in a safe place outside of the project. An .apk is an application package, it has nothing to do with the keystore.

Comment: @ferdy182 The keystore file is what I'm trying to find. Elipse seems to have replaced it with the apk. Can I generate the keystore again without changing it?

Comment: How would Eclipse replace the keystore with the apk? That is not possible

Comment: @ferdy182 Ok So where is the keystore? When you upgrade with Eclipse through the wizard the end result is the apk. I'm trying to upgrade through Android Studio and can't find the  Eclipse generated keystore anywhere. The studio wizard doesn't pick it up nor does a file search on the hard drives. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does not replace the the keystore file with the apk. The problem is that the keystore is saved in the original place where the finished package is saved. If you subsequently save your package to a different place Eclipse will access the original keystore file from where it was originally saved but will not show you where that is.
The problem is finding it. If you want to use Android Studio to access the keystore it suggests that you need a keystore with the file extension jks. A search for jks files will not show the Eclipse generated keystore files as they don't have any file extension at all.
Find the place where you've saved the original Eclipse package and you'll find the keystore (unless you deliberately saved it elsewhere). From there use Android Studio to build your package with 'use existing keystore' checked. Navigate to where the Eclipse keystore is saved and follow prompts from there.
The moral is - know where the keystore file is saved!

Comment: My keys in Eclipse are saved in a different folder but the key still have the applicationame.apk the file is only 3Kb Just rename it to applicationname.jks